# PHP 8.0.30 - directory-reading functions won't read all files

Tags: php

That's right. I used opendir() and readdir() to read a specific directory for years and it always worked fine. I added a couple of text files yesterday (same conditions: permissions, ownership, etc.) as the rest of files but readdir() and glob() just refuse to see them. I'm using Fedora 38, PHP 8.0.30 and the same PHP scripts as ever. Help, please!

My code:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../COMMON/TESTS_SOURCE_FILES/'))
{
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
  {
    if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') 
    {
      array_push($v_fileArray, $entry);
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: I suspect you added them in a different directory than the one you're trying to read.

Comment: There's no reason why these functions wouldn't see the files if they're really there.

Comment: Barmar: 1) I checked this out AGAIN a couple of minutes ago.  2) You are absolutely right.  3) The $directory variable was initially the opendir() parameter and I just took it out to verify opendir() wasn't the culprit. It''s doing nothing right now.